# Alternative regex for {}

Tags: awk, regular-expression

I am trying to replace all of this line, but the numbers:

```
looktype="123"
```

so only the numbers show up.

Is this possible in any easy way?

```
{sub ("look type=\"[0-9]{0,3}", "TEST")}
```

I am trying this with `awk`, to no avail. I believe "sub" and {0, 3} are interfering.

Comment: What kind of `awk` you use? Older `gawk` versions need `--re-interval` option to handle intervals in regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pipe it through `sed` to extract only what's inside the quote characters.

e.g.

```
$ echo 'looktype="123"' | sed -r -e 's/^.*"([^"]+)".*/\1/'
123
```

Note that `-r` is specific to GNU sed, it tells sed to use extended rather than basic regexps.  Other versions of `sed` don't have it, or might use `-E` instead.  Otherwise write it in POSIX basic regular expression (BRE) as:

```
sed -e 's/^.*"\([^"][^"]*\)".*/\1/'
```

Comment: and if it's only numbers you are interested in, you could be even more specific with it to `sed -e 's/^.*"\([0-9]*\)"/\1/'`

Answer (score 3):

In [extended regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended) (ERE), `X{m,n}` means `X` repeated between `m` and `n` times. Awk implements extended regular expressions, however historical implementations of awk didn't have this brace syntax for repeat intervals. The [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_04) specifies that awk must support ERE, but many extant implementations are not compliant.

With GNU awk, [intervals](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Operators.html#index-interval-expressions-409) are supported only since version 4.0. With older versions, you can force gawk to be POSIX compliant by setting the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable to a non-empty value:

```
POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 awk '{sub ("looktype=\"[0-9]{0,3}", "TEST"); print}'
```

The default version of awk on some distributions is not gawk but mawk, which is smaller and faster. Mawk does not support brace expressions. [There's a patch for that](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=355442), but as mawk isn't being maintained, it isn't widely adopted.

When the repetition count is small, you can spell it out:

```
awk '{sub ("looktype=\"[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?", "TEST"); print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

In `awk` (assuming the *exact* input you have posted) you could also do this:

```
awk -F'=' '{print $2}' | sed 's/"//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative in GNU `grep` (which I'm assuming you have on account of the Ubuntu tag):

```
grep -o '[0-9]\+' your_file
```

An even more portable alternative with Perl

```
perl -nle '/([0-9]+)/ and print $1' your_file
```

The two alternatives aren't exactly the same. They behave differently if you have several instances of a string of digits on the same line. The `grep` statement will print every occurrence of digits on a separate line while the `perl` statement will only print the leftmost occurrence of a string of digits in each line. This is due to the difference in the internal implementation of the regular expressions engine between `grep` and Perl.